# How can I copy more than 300 pictures with the Ubuntu file manager?

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

If i have a folder with over 300 pictures I'm unable to copy it with the Ubuntu built-in file manager from one file manager window to an other one; it gets stuck at the middle and I then need to log out/log in to start my file manager again.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. How can I copy large folders in the file manager?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Terminal instead of the file manager:

1. press <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or choose *Terminal* from the launcher
2. navigate to the source directory by typing `cd /path/to/source`
3. use `cp * /path/to/destination` to copy all files to the desired destination directory. Don't worry, if this takes a while and you don't get any output.
4. check the content of your destination directory

Note:
If you have other files than the 300 Pictures in the Directory, you may want to use something like `*.jpg` instead of `*` in the `cp` command to copy only files ending with `.jpg`.

Comment: It's not answer for the question @Wayne_Yux, as then i can remove the whole GTK+ stuff, Total commander is far more faster under wine also.